# Using a decoy traffic while using the internet

Tags: tor, internet, isp

Since the ISP knows what sites I visit and they can assume or predict that I'm using Tor if they are monitoring my traffic, how can I distract them by making them see that I visit some particular site when I'm visiting some other site.

To put simply, say if I am browsing say Reddit, my ISP will instead see that I'm on security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

You can not distract your ISP basically, there is no a human checking the traffic so he can be distracted. In general, ISP logs dns, ips, https and so on in the same way bro/snort/aiengine does. However there is some traffic generators that can make hard for an ISP to determine what you do, because basically you enter in 1000 sites every time. Have a look at https://github.com/ecapuano/web-traffic-generator for example, this may help you.

Comment: There might be humans checking the traffic if you live in China.

Comment: So just to clarify, I cannot set up my internet connection so that when I browse some sites, the ISP instead of keeping a log of those sites it keeps a log of some other sites which I have explicitly programmed it to.

Answer (score 0):

This is an active area of research that generally falls into the categories of censorship resistance and traffic obfuscation. Some approaches are [pluggable transports](https://www.torproject.org/docs/pluggable-transports) in Tor, [domain fronting](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_fronting), and [decoy routing](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/events/foci11/tech/final_files/Karlin.pdf).

What can you use today? As far as I know Tor’s pluggable transports are the main usable implementation, but they have downsides as well.